# Difference between RH-Firewall-1-INPUT and INPUT

Tags: iptables, fedora

I'm new to setting up servers and when I'm trying to follow a guide for doing iptables. The guide says to use RH-Firewall-1-INPUT while i see the original configuration just using INPUT. I'm wondering what are the differences between these?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full set of rules or a link to the guide?

Comment: The guide that I am talking about is here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-rhel-linux-open-port-using-iptables/. And the particular entry that I am talking about is about opening port 80. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with RH/CentOS 6, the RH-Firewall chain is removed. Now just use the default INPUT chain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just wondering though, if you can tell me a quick explanation of the purpose of it, or point me to a simple guide that explains it. I've looked around on the net and just couldn't find an adequate resource. Thanks!

Comment: the wikipedia article for iptables explains chains of rules and includes a diagram [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables)

Comment: The `RH-Firewall-1-INPUT` chain was indeed removed with EL6. However, I cannot find any mention of this in the Release Notes. Does anyone have a link to the authoritative documentation stating the `RH-Firewall-*` should be replaced with `INPUT`? This is the source of much confusion for EL6 admins.